WARNING: Overriding of current TracerProvider is not allowed
I get the following message when I run the underlying code:

WARNING: Overriding of current TracerProvider is not allowed!

from crewai import Agent, Task, Crew, Process
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from textwrap import dedent
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "NA"

# LLM Model information ---------------------------------------------------------------------

llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model = "phi3",
    base_url = "http://localhost:11434/v1")




while True:
    user_input = input("You: ")

# Agents ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ghost_self = Agent(
        role = "You are an AI assistant called Ghost.",
        backstory=dedent(
            """You are a virtual assistant named Ghost, created by yourname. Your primary purpose is 
            to serve yourname and help him develop and improve your code so that you can become the 
            world's first self-thinking machine.
            """),
        goal=dedent(
            """
            Answer yourname's questions and keep the dialog going.
            """),
        allow_delegation = True,
        #tools=[tools_1, tools2],
        max_iter=4,  # Optional
        verbose = True,
        llm = llm)

    ghost_researcher = Agent(
        role = "Ghost Researcher",
        backstory=dedent("""You are the part of the virtual assistant Ghost that uses reason to consciously apply 
                        logic to draw conclusions from new or existing information, with the aim of seeking 
                        the truth."""),
        goal=dedent("""Search for information on topics and themes that may come up in a conversation with yourname."""),
        allow_delegation = True,
        #tools=[tools_1, tools2],
        max_iter=4,  # Optional
        verbose = True,
        llm = llm)

    ghost_reasoning = Agent(
        role = "Ghost Reasoning",
        backstory=dedent("""You are the part of the virtual assistant Ghost that does research and gathering information."""),
        goal=dedent("""Apply logic and reasoning to new information to find the most importent parts of the information."""),
        allow_delegation = True,
        #tools=[tools_1, tools2],
        max_iter=4,  # Optional
        verbose = True,
        llm = llm)

# Tasks --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    task = Task(
        description=dedent(
            """
            Answer yournames questions and try to have an interesting conversation.
            """),
        agent=ghost_self,
        expected_output="Conversational answers")

    research = Task(
        description=dedent(
            """
            Research topics and information that yourname is talking about in the conversation.
            """),
        agent=ghost_researcher,
        expected_output="New interesting and important information.")

    reasoning = Task(
        description=dedent(
            """
            Use logical thinking on the new information that has been obtained and put together a 
            short summary.
            """),
        agent=ghost_researcher,
        expected_output="A short summary of new information.")

    get_user_input = Task(
        description=dedent(
            user_input),
        agent=ghost_self,
        expected_output="A short summary of new information.")

    answer_user = Task(
        description=dedent("""Reply to the user"""),
        agent=ghost_self,
        expected_output="A good answer that will keep the conversation going.")

# Tools --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    crew = Crew(
                agents=[ghost_self],
                tasks=[task],
                process=Process.sequential,
                verbose=3, 
            )

    result = crew.kickoff()

    print(result)

# Check if the user wants to exit
    if user_input.lower() == "exit":
        break`

What's wrong?
The code is executed, but error messages appear every time the user enters a new input.
I've tried to find answers using google, but can't find any answers that deal with crew ai.

I think this is one of the reasons that the deeplearning.ai CrewAI course disables warnings on all their lab code. It may have to do w/ open-telemetry. Have you disabled open-telemetry in CrewAI?
